# Repeated "Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, display-resolution

I'm running 16.04 and have had no DNS related issues for a few months. Today, I started seeing the error

> Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

when trying to create a new connection. I can ping IP addresses fine, but it seems like not even domains in my `/etc/hosts` can be resolved.

The strange thing is, that doing

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

fixes the issue for a few minutes. However, it soon breaks again and I have to re-run the command.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could be a corrupted cache issue, try flushing the dns cache `sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart`

Comment: So, this was happening on my work computer. Weirdly enough, I didn't have the issue at all today. It might have been somehow related to the office WiFi. Will try your solution if I ever see it again @MatsK

Comment: I had the same error message when trying to `!pip install` in a Kaggle notebook, without the internet being switched on in the settings of that notebook, see [Connection error with '!pip install torchxrayvision' on kaggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65477661/connection-error-with-pip-install-torchxrayvision-on-kaggle). That is why I guess that you just lose the internet connection after some minutes for whatever reason.